# Regex get all possible occurrence in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `s = '10000'`,
I need using only the ***Python re.findall*** to get how many `0\d0` in the string `s`
For example: for the string `s = '10000'` it should return 2

explanation:
the first occurrence is 1**0**0**0**0 while the second occurrence is 10**0**0**0**

I just need how many occurrences and not interested in the occurrence patterns

I've tried the following regex statements:

```
re.findall(r'(0\d0)', s) #output: ['000']
re.findall(r'(0\d0)*', s) #output: ['', '', '000', '', '', '']
```

> Finally, if I want to make this regex generic to fetch any **number** then
>   **any_number_included_my_number** then **the_same_number_again**, how can I do it?

Comment: Capture in lookahead using `(?=(0\d0))`: `re.findall(r'(?=(0\d0))', s)` outputs `['000', '000']`

Comment: For the second one, I'm assuming you mean something like `(\d)\d\1`?

Comment: @ctwheels It works perfectly, you have saved my life, thanks a lot, post it as an answer to mark it as accepted answer :)
could you give me some explanation for what is the ?= done to make it work

Comment: I've converted my comments into an answer, hopefully I've made it more clear :)

Comment: If it doesn't matter what the match is, can just use the bump-allong affect like this `res = re.findall(r"(?=(\d)\d\1)", targ)` the length of the res list tells how many found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to get all possible occurrences?

#### The regex

As I mentioned in my comment, you can use the following pattern:

```
(?=(0\d0))
```

How it works:

- `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches. This doesn't consume characters (allowing us to check for a match at each position in the string as a regex would otherwise resume pattern matching after the consumed characters).
- `(0\d0)` is a capture group matching `0`, then any digit, then `0`

#### The code

Your code becomes:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolatYwVZB3dAACNS5KoDsolS9tMy8lMScHI0idQ17Ww2DmBQDTU11HYViTa6Cosy8Eo0Kzf//AQ)

```
re.findall(r'(?=(0\d0))', s)
```

The result is:

```
['000', '000']
```

The [python `re.findall` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) states the following

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

This means that our matches are the results of capture group 1 rather than the full match as many would expect.

---

## How to *generalize* the pattern?

#### The regex

You can use the following pattern:

```
(\d)\d\1
```

How this works:

- `(\d)` captures any digit into capture group 1
- `\d` matches any digit
- `\1` is a backreference that matches the same text as most recently matched by capture group 1

#### The code

Your code becomes:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##DcY7DoAgDADQnVN0o02M8TMbDwIMJmgk0UIKA54eedNLX7kjr62FN0UpIKfKsIGep06r2i/neAX2x/OgaNw3ROvJersQ6QEyqSSBCxo2k4MrCjAEhuqotR8)

```
re.findall(r'(?=((\d)\d\2))', s)
print([n[0] for n in x])
```

Note: The code above has two capture groups, so we need to change the backreference to `\2` to match correctly. Since we now have two capture groups, we will get tuples as the documentation states and can use list comprehension to get the expected results.

The result is:

```
['000', '000']
```

Comment: Thanks, it's really a very useful answer, I found that we can also do it without the \d in the pattern (\d)\d\1 to be something like that (.)(?=.\1)

Comment: @MohamedMohsen yes, you can also do it that way, but `\d` ensures it's a digit whereas `.` matches any character except newline characters.